# How to make two divs in one line while reversing them (wordpress)?

Tags: html, wordpress, flexbox

I need to put two buttons in one line reversely.
I tried following code, but no changes, they are still in two lines.
Would you please let me know how to solve this?

[image] => [image]

Existing code:

```
<form class="acf-fields">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="custom-warp-button">
    <div class="acf-form-submit">
        <div class="acfef-submit-buttons">
            <input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button"  value="Sbumit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="save-progress-buttons">
        <input formnovalidate="" type="submit" class="save-progress-button" value="Save Draft" name="save_progress">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Code I trid:

```
.acf-fields div.custom-warp-button  {
display: flex!important;
flex-direction: row-reverse!important;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shown in one line for me:

```css
.acf-fields div.custom-warp-button  {
display: flex!important;
flex-direction: row-reverse!important;
}
```

```html
<form class="acf-fields">
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="custom-warp-button">
    <div class="acf-form-submit">
        <div class="acfef-submit-buttons">
            <input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button"  value="Sbumit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="save-progress-buttons">
        <input formnovalidate="" type="submit" class="save-progress-button" value="Save Draft" name="save_progress">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your hlep. yeah, it should be working, but it just doesn't work in my page. So I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: open developer console and compare styles for both elements and it's parent here and on your page.

Comment: Hi vanowm: Oh.. You are right, I created the <div class="custom-warp-button"> using jQuery, and it did't work with css. I added style direct to the div. Now it works. Thanks a lot for your supportive help : )

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS

```
.acf-fields div.custom-warp-button  {
  display: flex!important;
}
.acf-fields div.custom-warp-button .acf-form-submit{
  order:2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/xz0dcfn9/4/

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your hlep. I copy and pasted your code, but it just doesn't work in my page.. I'm not sure why... No error in console..

Comment: Hi Lalji Tadhani: Thank you a lot for your help. Your code works very well : )